# What is this + (plus) in trait bounds?

Tags: rust, syntax

Explain this line of Rust code (what is `+`?):

```rust
pub struct BlinkAlloc<A: Allocator = +Global> {
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Where did you see this?

Comment: @kmdreko https://github.com/zakarumych/blink-alloc/blob/main/src/local.rs#L90

Comment: @kmdreko `cargo test` outputs no errors.

Comment: That is within a macro, meaning the code within doesn't have to abide by Rust's normal syntax. You'd have to consult the macro to see what the extra `+` signifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking at [this](https://github.com/zakarumych/blink-alloc/blob/06de89690c7d15bb5748ad187b47974e0359cf24/src/local.rs#L90):

```
pub struct BlinkAlloc<A: Allocator = +Global> {
    arena: ArenaLocal,
    allocator: A,
}
```

This is not valid Rust syntax... usually. But this struct definition is actually inside a [macro call](https://github.com/zakarumych/blink-alloc/blob/06de89690c7d15bb5748ad187b47974e0359cf24/src/local.rs#L16).

This crate uses a complex system of macros, which I didn't spend the time to understand. It also doesn't document the supported syntax, so I would only be guessing if I gave any interpretation for what it actually means.